# DOJO - Close dojo tooltip if connected id is removed

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am newbie on dojo and trying to setup the tooltip.

I have a element that is generated dynamically and i create a id attribute on the same to attach a tooltip to the element, when user hover on it, Dojo tooltip appears, when user click on it the element get removed and created again dynamically without the id, so the connected Tooltip get remain active and i am not able to close it, is there any way to hide the tooltip if connected id is removed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide your source !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your efforts bRIMOs Bor, But dojo tooltip uses connected id as a reference where to show the tooltip, we can't close a tooltip by getting element connected id when user mouseover the connected id.

Here is the code which worked for me. I just removed the dijitTooltip Class from the mastertooltip, which make a tooltip visible.

```
dijit.Tooltip._masterTT.containerNode.innerHTML='';
dojo.removeClass(dijit.Tooltip._masterTT.id, "dijitTooltip");
```

Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 0):

So , when you click on the element , that element get removed , so before it get removed get it's (click with event args in claback function ,get the id by `event.target.id` or `this.id` if event directly connected to the node)

after getting that `Id` you can hide the tooltip

```
var element = dojo.byId(Id);
yourTooltip.hide(element);
```